# How can I save/ backup the contents of each users ROOM database online?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-database

My application (a workout tracker) relies quite heavily on a ROOM database.

This is where all of the customers data, as well as exercise info is stored.

However the problem with this is that if a user changes phone, or deletes the app all of the data is lost.

How can I backup this data/ is there a way to save the contents of each users ROOM database online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another datasource to sync your data.
ie, you should design a database on a server, write an api and put your data on the online database.
If you don't have knowledge of web programming, maybe [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) can help you.